# Derivable 'infinite times'..

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My professor left me with a question: given an infinite times derivable function, and provided $f^{(4)}(x)=0$ and $f^{(5)}(x)$ different to $0$, what is the value of $x$?

Comment: I would look towards Taylor's theorem, but you probably need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example...

$$f(x) = \sin(x)$$

Indeed this is a periodic infinitely derivable function (like many others).

$$f^{(4)}(x) = \sin(x)$$

$$f^{(5)}(x) = \cos(x)$$

For $x = 0$ the fourth derivative is zero, and the fifth is $1$.

Comment: Thank you sir, I had to look upon Taylor's theorem to get it clear to me, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @GiorgioVitanza You're welcome! Sometimes one just can go by intuition and experience :) There are lots of other examples, but yeah take a look at Taylor's theorem too!! The more you know the better!

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a function $f(x)$ such that it satisfies the criterion.

See that $C\times f(x)$ also satisfies the criterion.

So either any solution can be multiplied by a arbitrary constant to make any solution be correct...

Or there is the unique solution $f(x)=C\times f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless more is known about f, there is no unique answer.  Consider f(x) == sin(x).  The fourth derivative is again sin(x), the fifth is cos(x), and these are zero and nonzero, respectively, at any multiple of pi.

(DRAT! BEAT ME TO IT BY -THAT MUCH-)

Comment: Yeah, how difficult to write something I already wrote.